# JQuery .on Selector with Dynamic Divs Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, events, onclick

There is a lot of resources on this subject, but I've been going in circles for the last hour. Can someone help me out?

I've got this code:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#init').click(function() {
        var width = parseInt($('#width').val());
        var height = parseInt($('#height').val());
        var multX = parseInt($('#multX').val());
        var multY = parseInt($('#multY').val());
        var tileSize = parseInt($('#tileSize').val());
        var nTiles = ((width * multX) / tileSize) * ((height * multY) / tileSize);
        BuildMap(width, height, multX, multY, tileSize);
      });

      function BuildMap(width, height, multX, multY, tileSize) {
        var cols = (width / tileSize) * multX;
        var rows = (height / tileSize) * multY;
        var tileSizeX = Math.floor((1800 / cols));
        var tileSizeY = Math.floor((1000 / rows));

        var index = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            $('#map').append('<div class="tile" id="' + index + '" style="width:' + tileSizeX + 'px;height:' + tileSizeY + 'px;"></div>');
            index++;
          }
        }
      }

      $('#map').on('click', '.tile', function() {
        console.log('j');
        $(this).css({
          'background-color': 'red'
        });
      });
    });
```

```css
    #map {
     width: 1800px;
     height: 1000px;
     line-height: 0;
     margin-right: 40px;
    }
    
    #mapWrap {
     overflow: auto;
    }
    
    #wrap {
     width: 800px;
     height: 400px;
    }
    
    #select {
     width: 200px;
     display: inline-block;
    }
    
    #terrainSelect {
     float: right;
     height: 300px;
     width: 220px;
     top: 0;
    }
    
    .terrain {
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     padding: 10px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .tile {
     padding: 0px;
     margin: 0px;
     display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="container" id="wrap">
     <h2>MAPEDITOR</h2>
       <div id="select">
       viewport width:<br>
       <input type="number" name="width" value="1800" id="width">
       <br>
       viewport height:<br>
       <input type="number" name="height" value="1000" id="height">
       <br>
       multX:<br>
       <input type="number" name="multX" value="4" id="multX">
       <br>
       multY:<br>
       <input type="number" name="multY" value="4" id="multY">
       <br>
       tileSize:<br>
       <input type="number" name="tileSize" value="32" id="tileSize">
       <br><br> 
       <input type="submit" value="init" id="init">
       </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="container" id="mapWrap">
      <div id="map"></div>
     </div>

     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="map.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

For whatever reason, the click event handler for #map is not firing. I can see that the class is being set on each appended element. Anyone have any ideas? I'm using jquery 3.4

Comment: Is that HTML with `#map` static or dynamic (is it added via a script?)

Comment: Can you add enough code so we can run the snippet? Add the `init` button and fill in the values for the arguments to `BuildMap`.

Comment: map is written out in the html file, so static I believe @JackBashford

Comment: @Barmar added a few more bits

Comment: I think you need to add some CSS so we can see the tiles when they're added.

Comment: @Barmar css is up

Comment: I still can't see the tiles, but if I click randomly I sometimes hit one, and the code works.

Comment: so you have gotten the console to print "j"? @Barmar

Comment: seems to be only working on the last row of the tileset.. something else going on here. Thanks

Comment: It works for me in all rows. I changed it to viewport height and width 100 to create big tiles.